# Does Facebook have any plans to promote a business page automatically for free?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Our company's Facebook page recently got a lot of likes (about 140 in three days) and we don't know how these likes came.

1. Nobody shares the page
2. We don't know how people liked our page
3. All people are Iranian (We are in Iran, too)

So I think Facebook itself promotes our page to others. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll find your answer by reviewing Insights of your page.

Click on "See All" of page insights and then click on "Likes" to find out the source of your likes!

Well, the answer is yes! Facebook recommends pages by a system called "Like Your Favorite Pages" or simply called Facebook recommendations.